# Is it possible to close browser window from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to close the browser window using JavaScript. Is this possible?

Comment: this site does it: http://www.thewildernessdowntown.com/

Answer (score 2):

```
window.close();
```

Comment: This is the only way. In modern browsers, it works only if the current window has been opened by a script instance; otherwise, a warning dialog will be shown or nothing will happen at all.