# Onclick in an html button, close browser using python

Tags: python, django, browser

I would like to create a website that when a button is clicked, the browser(and not only one tab) closes.

I thought to create a button inside a form that calls the python function

e.g [for html]:

```
<form action=?? method="GET">
     <input type="submit" value="close browser">
</form>
```

e.g [for python]:

```
import webbrowser

def close_browser():
  webbrowser.close()
  return None
```

How could I call the close_browser() function from html/JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

For the time being, Python is not a client-side (browser) scripting language. It's javascript or coffeescript or some other options... .

When it comes to javascript, your question is a duplicate from:

[Is it possible to close a browser window using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455426/is-it-possible-to-close-a-browser-window-using-javascript)